# JavaScript cannot insert variable value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert the value of the variable `newData123` into the `test` attribute.

But it inserts the variable name `newData123` instead of its value `456`...

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited**

The reason why I don't directly use `elm.setAttribute('test', 'newData123');` is that I need to pull the data **dynamatically** from another script like the below:

```
const newData123 = '456',
   newData456 = '789';
```

And that is why I need to use the template literal here in a **programmatic** way instead of hard code it.

```js
const elm = document.querySelector('.test'),
  data = '123',
  newData123 = '456';
  
elm.setAttribute('test', `newData${data}`);

const check = elm.getAttribute('test');

console.log(check);
```

```html
<p class="test"></p>
```

Comment: Try ```var newData123 = '456'; elm.setAttribute('test', window[`newData${data}`]);```

Comment: @User863 It returns `undefined`...

Comment: Take a look again. I used `var newData123`

Comment: @User863 Yes, that works! But what si the logic behind it? Why is the `const` not work but the `var` does? And what the `window` does? Please explain...I'm trying to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much safer if you formatted all your `newData` variables into an object of some sort.

```js
const data_obj = {
  newData123: '456',
  newData456: '123'
}
const data = '123'
console.log(data_obj[`newData${data}`]) // 456

const data2 = '456'
console.log(data_obj[`newData${data2}`]) // 123
```

Since JS is a little fuzzy with datatypes, you could even do something like this, which would require minimal refactoring:

```js
const newData = {
  123: '456',
  456: '123'
}
let data = '123'
console.log(newData[data]) // 456

data = '456'
console.log(newData[data]) // 123
  
console.log(newData[123]) // 456
```